# Copy previous value row if not nan based on another column if value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame d1 where I would like to copy over the values of all rows in all columns when column 'C' is lower than 10k. Obtaining the result indicated on d2. This without overwriting the values of the row  in case is different from Nan. On my example i have all values equal to '1' but on my real dataframe some of them are also different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding was correct, `df2` would be seen as an unexpected result, and the expected result would be

[image]

To achieve the result shown by the above screenshot, we only need to run the below code

```
df_result = df1[df1.C < 1000]
```

In addition, it would be better (closer to convention) to use `np.nan` than `nan`, with `import numpy as np`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, nope d1 is the output of a script and from d1 i need to get to d2 to carry on with the work that i have to implement. thanks

Comment: @SimAzz It would be better that the question is edited. Then I will try to look into it again.

Comment: i'm already using numpy, i have just wrote 'nan' for the example.